# Build parser from grammar at runtime

Tags: c++, parsing, runtime, grammar, parser-generator

Many (most) regular expression libraries for C++ allow for creating the expression from a string during runtime. Is anyone aware of any C++ parser generators that allow for feeding a grammar (preferably BNF) represented as a string into a generator at runtime? All the implementations I've found either require an explicit code generator to be run or require the grammar to be expressed via clever template meta-programming.

Comment: Generating code for whole parsers at runtime is powerful but probably not needed. Unless you really must support abritary BNF grammars (what for, by the way?), one can probably write a parser that is flexible enough to accomodate to some variations in the grammar with relatively little trouble.

Comment: @delnan, generating parsers in runtime is quite a usual thing in the Lisp world, especially now, in the Packrat era. But, in order to do the same in C++ one would have to bend to Greenspun's Tenth Rule.

Comment: And what's the problem with meta-programming? What can be easier than creating a parser with Spirit or AXE? Frankly, I don't know of any BNF-like parser generators that would beat those two in ease of use, performance, or ... anything. Just define grammar and semantics for your input and you are good to go.

Comment: @delnan I wrote something like that once - it was a full Earley parser that was constructed on-the-fly from a grammar file. My code was replacing existing code (that only handled CFGs by expanding them to regular grammars by brute force), and we had to use existing grammar files. But it could have been done differently (and more efficiently) in another context. It was in C, and I was looking for a similar thing at the time.

Comment: @Gene The problem is that the grammar is user specified at runtime. Meta-programming simply isn't possible.

Comment: @tgoodhart -- don't you have grammar for your run-time grammar? It's just an extra translation layer, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to build a recursive descent, backtracking parser that accepts a grammar as input.  You can reduce all your rules to the following form (or act as if you have):

```
 A = B C D ;
```

Parsing such a rule by recursive descent is easy: call a routine that corresponds to finding a B, then one that finds a C, then one that finds a D.  Given you are doing a general parser, you can always call a "parse_next_sentential_form(x)" function, and pass the name of the desired form (terminal or nonterminal token) as x (e.g., "B", "C", "D").

In processing such a rule, the parser wants to produce an A, by finding a B, then C, then D.  To find B (or C or D), you'd like to have an indexed set of rules in which all the left-hand sides are the same, so one can easily enumerate the B-producing rules, and recurse to process their content.  If your parser gets a failure, it simply backtracks.

This won't be a lightning fast parser, but shouldn't be terrible if well implemented.

One could also use an Earley parser, which parses by creating states of partially-processed rules.

If you wanted it to be fast, I suppose you could simply take the guts of Bison and make it into a library. Then if you have grammar text or grammar rules (different entry points into Bison), you could start it and have it produce its tables in memory (which it must do in some form).  Don't spit them out; simply build an LR parsing engine that uses them.  Voila, on-the-fly efficient parser generation.
You have to worry about ambiguities and the LALR(1)ness of your grammar if you do this; the previous two solutions work with any context free grammar.

Comment: and the moral of this story is that every LL(\*) grammar can be transformed to any other LL(\*) grammar, so in effect specifying grammar at run time is no different than specifying another grammar at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an existing library for this. However if performance and robustness are not critical, then you can spin off bison or any other tool that generates C code (via popen(3) or similar), spin off gcc on the generated code, link it into shared library and load the library via dlopen(3)/dlsym(3). On Windows -- DLL and LoadLibrary() instead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to embed some scripting language or even a full-blown VM (e.g., Mono), and run your generated parsers on top of it. Lua has quite a powerful JIT compiler, decent metaprogramming capabilities and several Packrat implementations ready to use, so probably it would be the least effort way.

Comment: I am considering this route. I know Lua has some nice C++ bindings that look promising. Nevertheless I'm hoping the crowd is aware of a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this http://cocom.sourceforge.net/ammunition++-13.html

The last one is an Earley Parser and it appears to take the grammar as a string.

One of the functions is:

> Public function `parse_grammar'
>
> ```
>          `int parse_grammar (int strict_p, const char *description)'
> ```
>
> is another function which tunes the parser to given grammar.
>     The grammar is given by string `description'.
>     The description is similiar YACC one.

The actual code is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/cocom/

**EDIT**

A newer version is at https://github.com/vnmakarov/yaep

Answer (score -1):

[boost::spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/about-2/) is a C++ parsing framework that can be used to construct parsers dynamically at runtime.

Comment: "Represented as a string"?!? No way.