# C library that takes a BNF definition and parses accordingly?

Tags: c, parsing, bnf

I'm looking for a library that can take a string that defines a BNF and another string that has the text to parse and parses the latter according to the former. Note that I don't want something that requires writing the definition in a source code form that then needs to be compiled

Comment: Perhaps [**Sweet Parser**](http://www.sweetsoftware.co.nz/parser_overview.html) or something similar? I apparently has the c/c++ parser written (lalr?) that will auto-recognize the language the BNF represents. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: There's one used in this [online book](http://www.buildyourownlisp.com/), written by the author.

Comment: What do you intend to do after having parsed, and the parser says "yes" or "no"?

Comment: No matter what you do, you're going to need a "the definition of the source code" to be parsed, because that's what BNF *is*.  Why do you object if it gets "compiled"?

Comment: @IraBaxter: The parser needs to reply with "no" if the text cannot be parsed according to the rules (e.g., the rules are for C syntax but the text is in Haskell. this is just an example, i'm not after programming language parsing). If "yes" is returned then the expression tree is returned, for further analysis.

Comment: @IraBaxter: The definition is dynamic and given by the user. So it is not part of the application.

Comment: Be very careful about what you call BNF.  Many so-called BNF parsers use a reduced syntax which has the same idea but is not BNF.  For instance, many drop the angle brackets, the ::= .  Some have been extended to include [] and {} for repetitions.  Some resemble JSON more than BNF.

Comment: I answered a different question that I think is the same answer for you.  You want to specify the grammar and the text to be parsed as a string?  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392302/build-parser-from-grammar-at-runtime/22797616#22797616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[libmarpa](https://github.com/jeffreykegler/libmarpa) which implements the [Marpa algorithm](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html), does general BNF parsing. However, it doesn't accept a BNF as a string — you need to build the grammar from the string and the lexer as, e.g., in this [JSON parser](https://github.com/jeffreykegler/libmarpa/blob/master/test/json.c).

Only a half of what you've asked for, but arguably the hardest half.

In a meanwhile, [Marpa::R2](http://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2) based on libmarpa does exactly what you need -- takes 
a string describing BNF and lexer rules and builds the recognizer -- a parser you can use directly to produce an AST or evaluate it via semantic actions.

There are efforts to wrap libmarpa conveniently to do what you said [1](https://github.com/jddurand/marpaXml), [2](https://github.com/jddurand/marpaWrapper).

There is also a [Kollos project](https://github.com/jeffreykegler/Kollos) aimed at extending and wrapping libmarpa using Lua.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to parse only small files for the purpose of "is this valid syntax", you might do this with an Early parser.  Big files parsed this way will be pretty slow.

Your problem will be defining tokens; if you Earley-parse at the character level, you will get a parse but it will be worse than Early-parsing on language tokens.

If you want larger scale parsing, you'll need a tool that lets you define tokens and grammars.  This is the very thing you say you don't want.

If you want a tool that produces *trees*, you might be able to modify the Earley parser to produce trees.   But back to efficiency: if you want some scale, you're likely to need a library for managing the tree nodes.